# Does green pool water damage St. Augustine grass and plants?

Tags: pool, lawn

We are in a drought region and water conservation is in effect. My pool has turned green, very green.

Is the pool water ok for the grass?

I am not sure what will heat and sun would do to the pool plaster but I am aware the empty pools pose a floating danger.

Comment: Usually pool water contains a lot of chemicals that might not be good for grass.  Green water might mean agree is growing in it so it might be safe.  Pour some on a small area and wait for a few days, if the grass stays/gets greener it should be safe.

Comment: measure the Ph of the pool

Answer (score 2):

Yes, yes, yes, you can use the pool water to irrigate your plants, or just pump it into the St. Augustine. St. Augustine is a particularly hardy type of grass. Pool water does not have any chemicals lethal to plants or animals, that's how you can jump into it. The green algae are just microscopic organisms that do photosynthesis, the same thing plants are doing all day long. The algae will die as soon as it hits the soil and dries. Absolutely no risk, unless you decide to drink it -- don't. The real danger of an open pool with unfiltered water is a child falling in it. [Drowning is the leading cause of death for children in the US.](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/07/08/health/children-drowning-deaths.html) That's a real danger.